# Windows 10 - Stop monitors from rearranging when one is turned off

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I'm using 3 monitors, 1 DVO (#3) and 2 DP, in the following order in real life (middle is main monitor, windows randomly numbered them)

[ 3 ] [ 2 ] [ 1 ]

#2 is set as my primary display.

Problem is, if I turn off # 1, windows re-arranges the monitors, and thinks they are in the following order:

[ 2 ] [ 3 ]

when in reality, #3 is to the left, so I need to move my mouse to the right in order to get to it.

Is there any way to prevent windows from doing this? I've been looking online for solutions but have not found an answer.

Comment: Sometimes the only fix for this is to either change the physical order, or swap the cabling to match.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to solve this problem by Windows tools.
An estimated solution would be to save the states of icons and windows for each display configuration.
And restore the appropriate one when necessary.
There are a lot of utilities for this, like:

https://github.com/mastersign/Mastersign.WinMan

http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/

http://www.softwareok.com/?site=Freeware/DesktopOK
....